# Google charts with jstl forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, bar-chart

Hi I am trying to render google chart on my java program. but it doesn't display at all. Google chart api is implemented in .jsp file. Since my java code delivers correct data (I checked with system print), there must be something wrong on my jsp file. specially [A] part.. 
I am very new to this world.

Can anyone point out what did I do wrong in .jsp file.

my jsp file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Data value');

data.addRows([
    <c:forEach var="dataIntValue" items="${dataInt}">
        ['${dataIntValue}'], //---- [A]
    </c:forEach>
    ]);    

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 340, min: 0});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 540px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**
when I look at the page source on browser.. it shows like this..

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Data Value');
        data.addRows([

                ['100'], 

                ['200'], 

                ['300'], 

                ['400'], 

                ['500'], 

                ['110'], 

                ['120'], 

                ['130'], 

                ['140'], 

                ['200'], 

            ]);    
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, {width: 1000, height: 540, min: 0});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 540px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the values are right ones.. but I don't know it should be with this '' together.. Can that be problem? e.g. it shows this ['400'], but may be should like this [400] without ''? but I don't know why it is with ''? what did I do in my code... and why with '400'? not just the value 400...

**update 2** 
applied the comment advice and then, get a syntax error , can't compile at all..

what I did based on advice: remove the ' ' in the [A]
so jsp file looks like this.. all same only [A] part is different by removing the ' '.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Data Value');
        data.addRows([
            <c:forEach var="dataIntValue" items="${dataInt}">
                [${dataIntValue}], //---[A]
            </c:forEach>   //----[B]
            ]);            //----[B]
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, {width: 1000, height: 540, min: 0});
      }   //----- [c]
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 540px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the syntax errors.. what I get after removing ' ' from [A]

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Syntax error on tokens, ArrayLiteralHeader expected 
 instead
- Syntax error, insert "]" to complete 
 MemberExpression
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
- Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayLiteral
```

**result here: can compile but no charts appears on browser: Comments from (JB Nizet)=> What you posted is not an error you get at runtime. It's an error that your IDE, which tries to interpret your code as pure JavaScript, generates. The code is correct. Deploy it, run it, ans see if it works**

**update 3 & solved: comma should be there in [A] and google chart code was problem should be like this:**

working code: 
1) changed to google.visualization.arrayToDataTable instead google.visualization.DataTable. 
2) I was missing first column element in here (so should have 2 elements like this) `['${dataIntValue}', ${dataIntValue}],` instead with only one element this was wrong: [${dataIntValue}],

Correct code=>

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

       //---[solution] modified from here
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['number', 'Data Value'],
           <c:forEach var="dataIntValue" items="${dataInt}">
                ['${dataIntValue}', ${dataIntValue}], 
            </c:forEach>
        ]);  //--- until here. 

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height: 340, min: 0});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 340px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The google API doesn't care how the JS code was generated. What does the generated page look like?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I added update part with page source on browser

Comment: It's `'400'` because you explicitely add quotes around numbers: `['${dataIntValue}']` should be `[${dataIntValue}]`. You also have a comma that shouldn't be there at the and of your array.

Comment: I tried it before. but only like this [${dataIntValue}] without ' '. I get compile error..it doens't work at all. I can't even compile.

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problem. If it does, then edit your question, and tell us which error you get.

Comment: Hi Thanks again. I've edited the question. you can look at the update 2 part .. it's all same from the original I just removed ' ' and use [${dataIntValue}] based on advice. then I've got all the syntax errors, I added these syntax errors as well.

Comment: What you posted is not an error you get at runtime. It's an error that your IDE, which tries to interpret your code as pure JavaScript, generates. The code is correct. Deploy it, run it, ans see if it works.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. yes, you are right. I can compile but still nothing appear on browser.. and I also removed comma (update 3 in the question) , still no chart appears on browser.

Comment: About comma, I also confused why it shouldn't be there.. other examples have comma at least the one I seen.... but... anyway. what about the DataTable in google api.   should I use google.visualization.arrayToDataTable? (this examples have comma) 
instead google.visualization.DataTable?

Comment: I know about the JSTL, but don't know about google charts.

Comment: Ah.. Ok.thanks anyway.. Just one last. In update 3, the syntax error [B] and [C].. Are those also not severe ? I mean this shouldn't cause any problem? It's syntax error, so makes me confuse since I new to all these

Comment: I solved it. Google chart was problem.. comma should  be there.. but still thanks a lot. Your comment stimulate by thoughts and JSTL part was really helpful. Thanks. thumbs up.